# Where are my "exchange" reminders in mac OS?

Tags: macos, reminders, exchange-activesync

I created reminders and lists in **exchange** section. I remember making some changes in internet accounts in system preference the other day. My notes disappeared after that. Can I recover them?

[image: There was supposed to be "exchange" category of reminders.]

Answer (score 1):

When the account is removed on iOS or macOS - the data is not deleted and only the local cache of it goes away. This is true for any sort of exchange or iCloud or google data lives in the cloud. Thus, the best way to find missing items would be to open the web client and look at the data store directly.

Once you verify that the data exists in the cloud - go ahead and add back that account on your Mac and enable the data classes you want (tasks map to reminders).